# How to sort alpha-numeric in jQuery DataTables

Tags: datatables

I am wondering if there is a build in solution in jQuery.DataTables to sort for an alpha numeric value (wrapped in html).

In my case I am rendering data like this (and this is also how its "sorted"):

- A1
- B5
- P10
- P11
- P12
- P1
- P2
- P3
- P4

Instead of this weird "sort" I am looking for a solution to sort it like this:

- A1
- B5
- P1
- P2
- P3
- P4
- P10
- P11
- P12

I've tried the **num** and **natural** sorting with the sType **html** (because its wrapped in a `<a />`)

Comment: Take a look at this working Demo https://plnkr.co/edit/nXpPypUfhDlRkyYGJuSs?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am wondering because I tried absolutely the same before. I guess I've forgot to insert the natural plugin - I thought it was build in!

Comment: Take a look at the comments section at this link: https://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/natural. It might help you If you will have an upper/lower case issue.